# How to apply timestamp option to all schema in Mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a lot of schema in my code and it is really difficult to add `{ timestamps: true }` to each of them one by one. How do I configure Mongoose to have timestamp enabled on every schema by default?

Comment: Check my answer below.  Let me know if was helpful or not 

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways you could do this:

Inside the schema:

```
const YourSchema = new Schema({
    timestamps: { type: Boolean, required: true, default: true }
});
```

Using middleware:

```
YourSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    this.timestamps = true
    next();
});
```